# Trouble with Character Detection in License Plate Recognition Using OpenCV and Tesseract OCR in Python

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I'm working on a license plate recognition system in Python using OpenCV for image processing and Tesseract OCR for character recognition. I've written a function to process the image of the license plate and extract text from it, but I'm encountering issues with detecting both large and small characters consistently. The function aims to sharpen the image, increase contrast, and apply various preprocessing steps before using Tesseract OCR.

```py
@staticmethod
def process_license_plate(frame, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    """
    Extracts and processes the license plate area from the frame using enhanced OCR.

    Parameters:
    - frame (numpy.ndarray): The image or video frame containing the license plate.
    - x1, y1, x2, y2 (int): Coordinates of the license plate bounding box.

    Returns:
    - str: The recognized text of the license plate.
    """
    # Step 1: Crop the license plate area
    license_plate_area = frame[y1:y2, x1:x2]

    # Step 2: Sharpen the license plate area using a kernel
    sharpening_kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1], [-1, 9, -1], [-1, -1, -1]])
    sharpened_license_plate = opencv.filter2D(license_plate_area, -1, sharpening_kernel)

    # Step 3: Increase contrast using CLAHE
    lab = opencv.cvtColor(sharpened_license_plate, opencv.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    l, a, b = opencv.split(lab)
    clahe = opencv.createCLAHE(clipLimit=3.0, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
    limg = opencv.merge([clahe.apply(l), a, b])
    enhanced_license_plate = opencv.cvtColor(limg, opencv.COLOR_LAB2BGR)

    # Step 4: Preprocess for OCR - Grayscale conversion, Gaussian blur, and Adaptive thresholding
    grayscale_license_plate = opencv.cvtColor(enhanced_license_plate, opencv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred_license_plate = opencv.GaussianBlur(grayscale_license_plate, (3, 3), 0)
    _, thresholded_license_plate = opencv.threshold(blurred_license_plate, 0, 255, opencv.THRESH_BINARY + opencv.THRESH_OTSU)

    # Step 5: Morphological operations to clean up the image
    morph_kernel = opencv.getStructuringElement(opencv.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
    opened_license_plate = opencv.morphologyEx(thresholded_license_plate, opencv.MORPH_OPEN, morph_kernel, iterations=1)
    inverted_license_plate = opencv.bitwise_not(opened_license_plate)

    # Step 6 1/2: Extract text using OCR
    license_plate_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(
        inverted_license_plate, lang='eng',
        config='--psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
    )

    return license_plate_text.strip()
```

I attempted to isolate the larger characters by using the height ratio of the license plate as a reference. However, as expected, this approach was not successful.

```py
# Step 6: Filter out smaller elements and keep larger characters (optional)
contours, _ = opencv.findContours(inverted_license_plate, opencv.RETR_EXTERNAL, opencv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
filtered_license_plate = np.zeros_like(inverted_license_plate)
# Define a threshold for contour area (e.g., 90% of the license plate area)
threshold_area = 0.9 * license_plate_area.shape[0] * license_plate_area.shape[1] # Debbuging values
for contour in contours:
    if opencv.contourArea(contour) > threshold_area:
        opencv.drawContours(filtered_license_plate, [contour], -1, (255, 255, 255), thickness=opencv.FILLED)
```

This is the end-result with the filter:

[image]

And this is the result without the filter

[image]

Comment: such tasks need to be solved with state of the art methods. tesseract OCR and manually figuring out how to filter the picture so tesseract will swallow it... is *not* state of the art. neural networks are state of the art. you should find or collect an annotated dataset. annotation: bounding box, relevant text on the license plate. let the model figure it out. it's a lot better at this.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I love the idea about leveraging "state of the arts" methods like neural networks, but the challenge lies in the execution speed. I'm curious to explore if there are programmable solutions to address this concern.

Comment: the quest continues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77813028/how-to-use-opencv-to-black-out-everything-in-an-image-except-for-license-plate-l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see 3 chars, a garden state icon, then 3 more chars.

Consider writing a routine that puts a bounding box on that NJ icon.
With that in hand, you're in a better position to find a bbox
for the 6 chars of interest.
You might also find that deleting pixels within the icon's bbox
improves OCR performance.

---

We see writing in several places, having large variations in font size.

Tesseract has some odd interactions with resolution.
Give it some clean PDF bitmaps of Helvetica characters,
and it works great over a smallish range of resolutions,
say 1 em being a dozen to a few dozen pixels.
Blow things up so we have a few hundred pixels per character,
and OCR performance falls apart.

Notice that the small font text was adequately recognized.
Here is some advice so Tesseract will ignore such distractor text:

1. Repeatedly blur, then sharpen, the image. This destroys fine print while leaving giant characters mostly legible.
2. Shrink your 400px tall image so it's closer to 80px tall. Again this destroys fine print while leaving giant characters mostly legible. And it puts us at the resolution where Tesseract shows better OCR performance.

If you're able to use bounding boxes to blank out distractors,
that is fair game as well.
But it's more sensitive to variation across plates and automobiles.
You might be able to use the vertical extent of
[connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)
to identify giant letters.
You'd expect to see at least six such components,
with similar baseline and similar height.

---

RGB color channel could help you out with relevant
masks for your greyscale images.
There's a relationship between the text "New Jersey"
and the foreground / background colors that can be used.
So identifying the state, and the color scheme,
could be a helpful early stage of your pipeline.

Comment: If I consistently reduce the size of my image with this process until it reaches a height of 80 pixels, wouldn't it result in a loss of resolution, potentially hindering Tesseract's ability to accurately identify characters?

Comment: Yes, that’s the point, the low resolution would hinder Tesseract’s ability to accurately identify the small characters such as we find on the license plate holder. I do not know the best number of pixels, you will have to experiment. The idea is to reduce resolution, until only the six large characters are legible to OCR.

Comment: but what if, in this instance, I'm trying to also find the state of the license plate. What is the most conviniant and reliable way to do it?

Comment: Honestly, for N "commonly seen" states you will have N closely related problems to solve. Solve one sub-problem at a time, starting with the most common cases. So you need an isNewJersey classifier, an isNewYork classifier, and so on. Having identified the state, you're in a better position to extract a NJ number or a NY number. Each state puts its own set of distractors into the image, which likely you will want to clean up to obtain good OCR performance.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the other answer, you have to play with the size and thresh of the balck & white image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
 
img = cv2.imread('plate.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
 
# Cropping an image and set color to B&W
cropped_image = img[150:265, 140:510] # img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(cropped_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(thresh, blackAndWhiteImage) = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 75, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 

# resize image
scale_percent = 46 # percent of original size
width = int(blackAndWhiteImage.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(blackAndWhiteImage.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
resized = cv2.resize(blackAndWhiteImage, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

# OCR resized Black & White image
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
custom_config = r'--psm 13 --oem 3 -l eng'
tex = pytesseract.image_to_string(resized, config=custom_config)
print(tex)

# Display cropped image
cv2.imshow("cropped", resized)
 
# Save the cropped image
cv2.imwrite("Cropped Image.jpg", resized)
 
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I know it might be a silly question, but what is the scale percentage, how does it affect the text recognition, how can I calculate it aswell based on the image size?