# How to use OpenCV to black out everything in an image except for license plate letters?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, image-preprocessing, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I'm trying to create a program that turns everything in an image black, except for the letters in a license plate area. I'm not sure where to start with this. I know I can use OpenCV in Python to load the image and access its pixel values, but how do I identify the bounding box of the license plate area in the image and set its pixel values to a specific color, like white? Additionally, how can I set the rest of the pixels outside the license plate area to black? Here's a starting point for my code:

```py
# Step 1: Crop the license plate area
license_plate_area = opencv.imread('image.png')

# Step 2: Sharpen the license plate area using a kernel
sharpening_kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1], [-1, 9, -1], [-1, -1, -1]])
sharpened_license_plate = opencv.filter2D(license_plate_area, -1, sharpening_kernel)

# Step 3: Increase contrast using CLAHE
lab = opencv.cvtColor(sharpened_license_plate, opencv.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
l, a, b = opencv.split(lab)
clahe = opencv.createCLAHE(clipLimit=3.0, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
limg = opencv.merge([clahe.apply(l), a, b])
enhanced_license_plate = opencv.cvtColor(limg, opencv.COLOR_LAB2BGR)

# Step 4: Preprocess for OCR - Grayscale conversion, Gaussian blur, and Adaptive thresholding
grayscale_license_plate = opencv.cvtColor(enhanced_license_plate, opencv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred_license_plate = opencv.GaussianBlur(grayscale_license_plate, (3, 3), 0)
_, thresholded_license_plate = opencv.threshold(blurred_license_plate, 0, 255,
                                                opencv.THRESH_BINARY + opencv.THRESH_OTSU)

# Step 5: Morphological operations to clean up the image
morph_kernel = opencv.getStructuringElement(opencv.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
opened_license_plate = opencv.morphologyEx(thresholded_license_plate, opencv.MORPH_OPEN, morph_kernel,
                                           iterations=1)
# Dilate the black region to include pixels outside the margin
dilate_kernel = opencv.getStructuringElement(opencv.MORPH_RECT,
                                             (5, 5))
dilated_license_plate = opencv.dilate(opened_license_plate, dilate_kernel, iterations=1)
# Invert the image so that the big words are black and the background is white
inverted_license_plate = opencv.bitwise_not(dilated_license_plate)
# Set any white pixels inside the black margin to black
for y in range(dilated_license_plate.shape[0]):
    for x in range(dilated_license_plate.shape[1]):
        if dilated_license_plate[y, x] == 0:  # Black pixel encountered
            inverted_license_plate[y, x] = 255  # Invert to white
        elif inverted_license_plate[y, x] != 0:  # White pixel encountered
            inverted_license_plate[y, x] = 0  # Keep it black

opencv.imshow('Window', inverted_license_plate)
opencv.waitKey(0)
opencv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: (1) read glyphs on plate (2) blank everything else -- if you think you need to blank out anything, you chose the wrong approach to license plate reading, "wrong" meaning "doesn't work" -- previous question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77775884/trouble-with-character-detection-in-license-plate-recognition-using-opencv-and-t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to make the outside of the license area all white in Python/OpenCV.

Read the input. Then threshold on black. Then get the largest external contour.  Use the contour to draw a white filled region on a black background as a mask. Use the mask to white out the area outside the license in the input. Save the results.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('license_plate.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# threshold on black
lower = (0,0,0)
upper = (0,0,0)
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# get largest external contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw white filled contour on black background as mask
mask = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, [big_contour], 0, (255,255,255), -1)
#mask = 255 - mask

# apply mask to input
scale = 1/255
result = 255-cv2.multiply(255-img, mask, scale=scale)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('license_plate_thresh.jpg', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('license_plate_mask.jpg', mask)
cv2.imwrite('license_plate_result.png', result)

# show the results
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Mask image:

[image]

Result image:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way that, I can mask the pixels on top or bottom of the license plate as well?

Comment: After doing the above, apply a horizontal morphology close filter to connect the white spots horizontally so that you have 3 regions, a top, a middle (your text), and a bottom.  The length of the filter needs to be large enout to connect the regions, but not so large that it connects to the white outside the license. Get contours and filter on the middle or most like the largest contour. Then create a mask again from that contour and use it the make the top and bottom regions in the image black.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want to read the number plate. In that case, you can use a library called [Tesseract OCR/pytesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)

Then it becomes simple:

```
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
results = pytesseract.image_to_data(rgb, output_type=Output.DICT)
```

The result will then include the bounding boxes of each localized text "group".
If you want the bounding boxes of the text aka number plate you can simple use.

```
for i in range(0, len(results["text"])):
    x = results["left"][i]
    y = results["top"][i]
    w = results["width"][i]
    h = results["height"][i]
```

Then you can darken all regions except the text area.

In case you want the text itself with confidence simply use `text = results["text"][i]` and `results["conf"][i]`

Comment: Yeah. Getting the bounding boxes for the letters seems to be the most logical solution for me. After that, it's just a matter of applying the same thresholding and morphological operations within the region to get the text "highlighted". Removes all the unnecessary noise which is not the number